# Will a PECL package for PHP 5.4 work with 5.5?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, memcached, pecl, amazon-elasticache

I'm looking to install the [Amazon ElastiCache Memcached Cluster Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.html#Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.Downloading) so I can take advantage of autodiscovery of cache nodes.

Unfortunately, it looks like they only available options are

- Java
- PHP 5.3 (64-bit Linux)
- PHP 5.3 (32-bit Linux)
- PHP 5.4 (64-bit Linux)
- PHP 5.4 (32-bit Linux)

The version of PHP that is installed on my EC2 instance is `PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1` (the default for Ubuntu).

Does anyone have any insight into whether or not the 5.4 package will work with PHP 5.5 or not? I did [find one person looking for this on their forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=139791&tstart=0) but there doesn't seem to be a resolution there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one way to find out, right? Well, the answer is no.

I followed the installation instructions and got this when I started up PHP:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcached: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```